# Use Enum-value without using Enum-classname

Tags: java, class, inheritance, enums

I use a static enum in an interface and want to use it in an extending class.

I have following interfaces:

```
public interface StateSupport {
    public static enum State {
        NEW,
        UNCHANGED,
        UPDATED;
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface Support extends StateSupport  {
    public void do(Context arg0);
}
```

and finally a class

```
public class MyClassUtil implements Support {
    public void do(Context arg0){ 
        MyClass obj = new MyClass(NEW);
    }
```

}

The point is that I dont want to write "State.NEW", just "NEW" :-)

So how can it do that without using the enum name. Is there a way at all?

Comment: Ugh, why would you want to go out of your way to make your code less readable?

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the reader. I for one prefer static imports whenever they are obvious enough (quite often, that is).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a static import:

```
import static com.yourpackage.StateSupport.State.NEW;
import static com.yourpackage.StateSupport.State.UNCHANGED;
import static com.yourpackage.StateSupport.State.UPDATED;
```

or in short (discouraged):

```
import static com.yourpackage.StateSupport.State.*;
```

Comment: @assylias yes but some metrics tells this as bad practice.

Comment: Importing * is discouraged because its meaning changes as other classes change, and because you can't know what a symbol refers to by just inspecting the compilation unit in which it occurs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Although I agree in general, for the static import of enum values I think it is acceptable (it is probably the only situation where I use the wildcard).

Comment: @assylias It is ok until you have **two** wildcard imports. Then it gets quite confusing.